Combining paths of two shapes after clipping in TikZ
I have two overlapping shapes in TikZ which I need to join together -- essentially, an union operation on geometry. For instance, when I have two overlapping triangles, one spanning beyond another, the process of path tracing is fairly easy. All I have to know is where do they intersect, then define the bisecting coordinates and finally draw by adding points and intersection vertices along the path of the complete shape.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections,positioning,calc}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\coordinate (A) at (0,0);
\coordinate (B) at (3,0);
\coordinate (C) at (1.5,3);
\coordinate (D) at (1,1);
\coordinate (E) at (4,1);
\coordinate (F) at (2.5,4);

% Define the first triangle path
\path[dotted,name path=triangle1,draw] (A) node[below] {A} -- (B) node[below] {B} -- (C) node[above] {C} -- cycle;

% Define the second triangle path
\path[dotted,name path=triangle2,draw] (D) node {D} -- (E) node {E} -- (F) node {F} -- cycle;

% Define line segments as named paths
\path[name path=lineCB] (C) -- (B);
\path[name path=lineDF] (D) -- (F);
\path[name path=lineDE] (D) -- (E);

% Find intersections of lineCB with other lines
\path[name intersections={of=lineCB and lineDF, name=intCBDF}];
\path[name intersections={of=lineCB and lineDE, name=intCBDE}];

\filldraw[blue!40,draw=black,thick] (A) -- (B) -- (intCBDE-1) -- (E) -- (F) -- (intCBDF-1) -- (C) -- cycle;

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}


The problem with the code is that it is extremely verbose and requires one to manually inspect where along the shapes does intersection occurs and how many of such would occur. Also, one needs to carefully trace the path in sequence drawing to generate a combined shape.
The other problem is that not every shape is simple like triangle. Uniting paths, therefore, becomes quickly intractable for complex shapes.
My current issue at hand is with following two shapes.
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections,positioning,calc,shapes.geometric}
\usetikzlibrary{ext.paths.arcto}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
%% Shape 1
\coordinate (W) at (0:0);

\def\teeth{12}
\def\innerR{1.4}
\def\outerR{2.4}
\pgfmathsetmacro\angle{360/\teeth)}

\draw[blue,fill=red!50] (W) circle [radius=\innerR];
\draw[blue,fill=red!50]
  \foreach \i in {1,2,...,\teeth} {%
     [rotate=(\i-1)*\angle]  ($(W) + (0:\innerR)$) -- ($(W) + (\angle*1/2:\outerR)$) -- ($(W) + (\angle:\innerR)$)
   };
   
%% Shape 2
\pgfmathsetmacro\radA{2.0}
\pgfmathsetmacro\radB{2.8}

\coordinate[label=left:A] (A) at (0, 0.25);
\coordinate[label=left:B] (B) at (0, 2.1);

\path[name path=CA] (A) circle (\radA);
\path[name path=CB] (B) circle (\radB);

\foreach \i in {A,B} {
  \filldraw[black] (\i) circle (0.4pt);
}

\path[name intersections={of=CA and CB, by={I1,I2}}];

\draw[fill=black!80] (I1) circle (1pt);
\draw[fill=black!80] (I2) circle (1pt);

% \draw[blue,fill=blue!50] (I1) arc to[radius=\radB,large,clockwise](I2)
% arc to[radius=\radA,large](I1) ;
\draw[blue,fill=blue!50] (I1) arc to[radius=\radA](I2)
arc to[radius=\radB,clockwise](I1) ;

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

I want to remove the spikes of Shape 1 (shapes are indicated by comment lines) that protrude below of Shape 2 and join the remaining shapes together so that I can fill them as a single path.


\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections, ext.paths.arcto}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\pgfmathsetmacro{\teeth}{12}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\innerR}{1.4}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\outerR}{2.4}
\draw[red, fill=red!50, save path=\star] (0:\innerR) \foreach \i in {1,...,\teeth} {-- ({(\i-0.5)*360/\teeth}:\outerR) -- (\i*360/\teeth:\innerR)} -- cycle;

\pgfmathsetmacro{\radA}{2.0}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\radB}{2.8}
\coordinate (A) at (0,0.25);
\coordinate (B) at (0,2.1);
\path[name path=CA, overlay] (A) circle (\radA);
\path[name path=CB, overlay] (B) circle (\radB);
\path[name intersections={of=CA and CB, by={I1,I2}}];
\draw[blue, fill=blue!50, save path=\moon] (I1) arc to[radius=\radA] (I2) arc to[radius=\radB,clockwise](I1) -- cycle;

\begin{scope}
\clip (\outerR,-\outerR) rectangle (-\outerR,\outerR) (-\outerR,-\outerR) -- (-\outerR,0) -- (I1) arc to[radius=0.5*(\radA+\radB)] (I2) -- (\outerR,0) -- (\outerR,-\outerR) -- cycle; %replace \clip with \fill[red] to see area
\fill[cyan!50, use path=\star];
\end{scope}
\fill[teal!50, use path=\moon];

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}



I learnt a lot! I didn't know about the save path option, nor did I realize I was drawing open path for star with the \foreach loop until you presented the code.

Just for comparison, here is how you could do that in Metapost using buildcycle.
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{luamplib}
\begin{document}
\begin{mplibcode}
beginfig(1);

  path star;
  star = for i=0 upto 23:
    if odd i: 100 else : 60 fi * down rotated 15i --
  endfor cycle;

  path crescent;
  numeric r; r = 48;
  crescent = (halfcircle rotated 180 scaled 2 .. 
    right {dir (180+r)} .. left {dir (180-r)} .. 
    cycle) scaled 85;

  % temporary drawing used to work out the right subpath
  % draw star;     
  % draw crescent;
  % for i=1 upto length crescent: 
  %   dotlabel.top(decimal i, point i of crescent); 
  % endfor

  path t; t = buildcycle(subpath (6,5) of crescent, star);

  fill t withcolor 7/8[red, white]; draw t withcolor red;
  fill crescent withcolor 7/8[blue, white]; draw crescent withcolor blue;

endfig;
\end{mplibcode}
\end{document}

Compile this with lualatex to produce a PDF like this:

If interested, you can follow the link at the top for tutorials and references for MP.

Thank you for getting the figure right. Unfortunately, It seems like I'm too stupid to understand any metapost code. The figure is, infact, a part of bigger TikZ document to be compiled with pdflatex, so no choice for me to move beyond that.

Sure, if you are not ready to switch to lualatex for the whole doc, you could insert a standalone PDF with includegraphics but I can see how that might complicate your build process...
